# Initialize a 2 Dimensional vector<int> in CPP

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, multidimensional-array, int

How to initialize a 2 dimensional `vector<int>` in C++?

For instance I have 4 arrays each of length 8 ints, like the below

```
int a1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int a2[] = {1,2,3,4,9,10,11,12};
int a3[] = {1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14};
int a4[] = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15};
```

and I have this

```
vector< vector <int> > aa (4);

aa[i] (a1,a1+8);
```

But this gives error. I even tried supplying the array a1 to v1 and passed v1 to `aa[i]` , still it fails.

So what would be the proper way of initializing the elements of a 2 dimensional `vector<int>`

Comment: Will each subarray have a length of exactly 8 ints? It might be easier to simply have a flat, one-dimensional array with `a1` occupying the first 8 spots, `a2` occupying the second 8 spots, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aa[i].assign(a1,a1+8);
```

Comment: +1 - This answer is better.  I was going to use `assign`, but was thrown off by the absence of `assign` on SGI's page.

Answer (score 2):

```
int arr[4][8] =
{
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  6,  7,  8},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12},
    {1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14},
    {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15},
};

std::vector<std::vector<int> > vec(4, std::vector<int>(8));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    vec[i].assign(arr[i], arr[i] + 8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of `aa` also initialized all four of the contained `vector<int>` objects, using the default constructor for `vector<int>`.  So you'll need to add data to those empty vectors, not initialize them.

Try for example:

```
std::copy(a1, a1+8, std::back_inserter(aa[i]));
```

Comment: you mean, `back_inserter(aa[i])`