# How to declare 2d arrays in array class

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, 2d

x[50][40] and y[50][40] are the 2d arrays. I am using array class. How to declare these in array class?

```html
array <array<long double>> x(50,array<long double>(40)),y(50,array<long double>(40));
```

I have used the above code in my program like the way a vector is declared as in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091647/initialize-a-2-dimensional-vectorint-in-cpp)
But getting errors. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <array>
...
typedef ::std::array< ::std::array< double, 40 >, 50 > t_My2dArray_50_40;
```